# Filtering an object JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a news aggregator using newsAPI, and have everything working - to begin with. But was wondering if the code I use to filter through an object can be made more efficient - meaning fewer lines of code.

So far, it only returns what I need from the raw JSON file, then filters it using a for loop to ignore objects with blank values.

Any help would be great.

```
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        let data = JSON.parse(body);

        let articles = data.articles.map(article => {
            return {
                "title": article.title,
                "date": article.publishedAt,
                "image": article.urlToImage,
                "description": article.description,
                "link": article.url
            }
        });

        let filtered = []
        for (let i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
            if (articles[i].title !== null &&
                articles[i].date !== null &&
                articles[i].image !== null &&
                articles[i].description !== null &&
                articles[i].link !== null) {
                filtered.push(articles[i])
            }
        }

        console.log(filtered)

        res.render("index", { filtered: filtered });

   }
```

Comment: Too lazy to write an answer. Array to hold property names, filter then map. `array.reduce` to transform each object. Chain them to avoid intermediates and you are done.        `const keys = [["title", "title"], ["publishedAt", "date"], ["urlToImage", "image"], ["description", "description"], ["url", "link"]];
        res.render("index", { filtered: JSON.parse(body).articles
            .filter(article => keys.some(key => article[key[0]] !== null)) 
            .map(article => keys.reduce((art, k) => (art[k[1]] = article[k[0]], art), {}))
        });`  BTW your code is missing a closing `}`

Comment: Looks like closing brace for the outer `if` is missing. That begs the question, is there other code missing?

Comment: Your code could be so much cleaner if you used the same property names throughout your code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `let` -> `const`
- Use the `Array` methods (`filter`, `every`)
- Use object destructuring
- Use object short-hand
- Use a method for the null check so you don't have to write it for every property

```js
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  const data = JSON.parse(body);

  const filtered = data.articles
    .filter(({ title, publishedAt, urlToImage, description, url }) =>
      [title, publishedAt, urlToImage, description, url].every(
        prop => prop !== null
      )
    )
    .map(
      ({
        title,
        publishedAt: date,
        urlToImage: image,
        description,
        url: link
      }) => ({
        title,
        date,
        image,
        description,
        link
      })
    );

  res.render("index", { filtered });
}
```

Update: filtered first for lower memory consumption as by @FreezePhoenix suggestion.

Comment: You seem to miss that the source properties and the rendered properties do not have the same name

Comment: @konijn Actually still had it wrong  Now it's fixed.

Comment: Hm... this creates a 2 new objects for each one being filtered... perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Not quite sure what you are getting at. Do you mean to lower the space complexity?

Comment: In my experience, for large projects (which this seems like it might grow into one), you want to squeeze almost every bit of memory you can out of it.

Comment: In my experience, for large projects, you want to maintain readability 

Comment: @Mohrn Your new edit in an attempt to incorporate my suggestion errors :) because none of the variables are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Revising @Mohrn's answer:

- Avoid creating new objects if possible.
- As mentioned by @radarbob, you are excluding the closing if bracket.

As such, I recommend a few changes be made:

```
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  const data = JSON.parse(body);

  const filtered = data.articles
    .map(
      ({
        title,
        publishedAt: date,
        urlToImage: image,
        description,
        url: link
      }) => (
        ([title, date, image, description, link].every(_ => _ !== null) ?
            { title, date, image, description, link } :
            null
      )
    )).filter(_ => _ !== null);

  res.render("index", { filtered });
}
```

This does result in fewer objects being created per iteration.

Comment: You're returning objects with the shape `{ title, publishedAt, utlToImage, description, url }` rather than `{ title, date, image, description, link }`. The difference between our solutions is that you lack the mapping of property names.

Comment: @Mohrn Edited, now the difference is that it doesn't create a second object for ones that don't need to be made. Instead of making the object and then getting values, we're getting values and then making the object if needed.